How do you shrink one end of a detailed spiral tube?
Im making a trunk of a Bonsai tree and im trying to shrink the end of the trunk smoothly. (Blue lines) Its not as simple as selecting one side and pressing s + y/x/z. As there is many polygons I also cant just select some and manually shrink them to size as it looks choppy. (Can be seen towards the base of the trunk). Any help would be great.



Hello what does it give if you enable the Proportional Editing option with the Linear fallof, and scale down?

If you model your trunk as a curve-bevel of a Bezier curve path, at least initially, then options become available to you, some of which are shown here:

You can adjust the resolution per-segment of the path, and the interpolation method between control-points, of the tilt (twist) and radius.
Rotations, scales, and positions of the control-points and their handles can be tweaked, to avoid sharp transitions and self-intersections.

Alt S will control the radius at selected control-points, and Ctrl T will control the tilt.
